# Cant implement a logo in exams2nops

Tags: r-exams

I have the problem to implement a logo in exams2nops. I dont no why, because the path is right. also i have used other formats beside .png. Is there a scale or size limitation present?

Does anyone has a clue?

Best regards,

JSP

Comment: Have you tried with an absolute path? That should work.

Comment: An absolute path should definitely work, it would be great if you could try that. Also, in the R-Forge version I have added a workaround that hopefully also resolves relative paths correctly. Maybe you can try that as well? Then I could write up a proper answer so that we can resolve this question.

Comment: Moin Mr Zeileis, it worked with the absolute path! Thank you! Of course it would be better and more fluid to work with relative paths especially then, when you work with an r-project and various computers... :) but we all know, that there is always a workaround. thanks for the update!